# File permission "b" of /var/lib/docker/volumes/backingFsBlockDev

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions

While poking around, I found the following file with weird permissions.

```sh
# ls -la /var/lib/docker/volumes/backingFsBlockDev
brw------- 1 root root 8, 3 Mar  4 10:15 /var/lib/docker/volumes/backingFsBlockDev
```

What does the `b` permission mean and when is it used?

Comment: It's not a permission. The first character is the type of file. `b` means block device.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.